# English translations of QGIS commands, algorithms and menu items

Tags: qgis, internationalization, translation

For posting here at GIS SE, I often have to find the English equivalents of commands, functions, algorithms, menu items etc. of my German language version of QGIS. Sometimes, a word-by-word translation results in the exact equivalent in an english-language QGIS-installation, but sometimes they are named quite differently. So it's an effort to always find the correct description to point to the relevant menu, algorithm etc.

Is there somewhere a kind of lexicon/dictionary with translations?

Something like:

german: Eigenschaften, englisch: properties

german: Werkzeugkiste, englisch: processing toolbox

etc.

To have a translation of the official QGIS terminology would help a lot.

Comment: You could use the documentation and exchange the "de" in the webadress for an "en" - and vice versa. For specific tools you can use the mouseover in the toolbox, there the internal name of the algorithm is shown (e.g. `native:extractbyattribute` = `Nach Attribut extrahieren`).

Comment: You can change the language of QGIS to English

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a search within https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qgis/QGIS/master/i18n/qgis_de.ts

You can also use https://www.transifex.com/qgis/QGIS/language/de/ (you need to create an account) to ease the search.

Personally, it's too bothering to search as you can have multiple occurrences of text matching, so I take another approach. I change the language by going to "Settings" > "Options", "Options - General" tab, clicking on "Override System Locale", choosing "User interface translation" to "American English" then restarting QGIS to get menus in English. Do my stuff and then reset to my language when finished.

Running the following PyQGIS enable to change language in the Processing toolbox items (PS: it does not change everything as some translation strings are enabled at QGIS startup)

```py
translator = QTranslator()
translator.load("qgis_de.qm", QgsApplication.i18nPath())
QgsApplication.installTranslator(translator)
```